# Blazor WebAssembly Can Not Load Files 404 Not Found

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I wanted to use .Net 6 hot reload features on my Blazor Webassembly app so I installed VS2022 Preview. When I tried to run my app my files loads resulted in 404 Not Found errors.

[image: My Errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the hosting runtime from MS here

```
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.0-windows-hosting-bundle-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69909787/8460873). Make sure you updated your NuGet packages to the latest version such as the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly` package. Also based on my experience, .NET 6 hot reload works only when running without a debugger, at least for now.